# Facing issue while building Corda Version 1

Tags: corda

I am getting below error while building Corda Version 1 (branch name - release-V1)

> Task :core:test

net.corda.core.flows.ContractUpgradeFlowTest > 2 parties contract upgrade using RPC FAILED
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException at ContractUpgradeFlowTest.kt:123

329 tests completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the project without running the tests by using the command `./gradlew build -x test` or `gradlew.bat build -x test`.

The integration tests can occasionally time-out, so I wouldn't be concerned by this issue. We are working to fix this.

In general, you shouldn't need to build Corda itself. The binaries for `release-V1` are published to Maven, so will be downloaded automatically. You should probably work from the templates:

- https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java
- https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin